# Is this true that all Mumins will eventually go to Paradise?

Tags: source-identification, jannah, mumin

A friend of mine told me few days ago that all of those who do believe in fundamental beliefs of Islam will ultimately go to Jannat, after suffering punishment (if awarded) for their sins in Jahannam.

It sounded misguiding information to me (Allah knows the best), but I neither accepted nor rejected the information because I do not know it for sure.

Is there any evidence of its being true or false?

Comment: According to Quran, only `Mumins` who did good deeds will enter to the Garden (Paradise) without any fear or sadness. According to Quran, being `Muslim` is not a guaranty for entering the Garden; there is no such guaranty given. Search for the definition of `Mumin` from reliable sources. Request references from Quran in the answers.

Comment: @AhmedHan: Why answering in comment?

Comment: This site is ruled by a group of people who vote answers and questions based on the person who write them. They don't seek correctness in an answer, but they seek it to fit their concurrent beliefs. I don't want to help this site get out of beta in this state, so I don't want to contribute by adding answers until (if) beta ends.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true, If a person has Iman (belief) and he didn't shirk, he eventually enters paradise.

As said here

> None shall enter the Fire (of Hell) who has in his heart the weight of a mustard seed of Iman and none shall enter Paradise who has in his heart the weight of a mustard seed of pride.<sup>[source](http://sunnah.com/urn/201650)</sup>

and here

> 'Ubadah bin As-Samit (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>   Messenger of Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said, "He who bears witness that there is no true god except Allah, alone having no partner with Him, that Muhammad is His slave and His Messenger, that 'Isa (Jesus) is His slave and Messenger and he (Jesus) is His Word which He communicated to Maryam (Mary) and His spirit which He sent to her, that Jannah is true and Hell is true; Allah will make him enter Jannah accepting whatever deeds he accomplished" - [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].
>
> Another narration in Muslim is: the Messenger of Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said, "Whosoever testifies that there is no true god except Allah and that Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah, Allah (SWT) saves him from the Fire (of Hell)". <sup>[source](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/412)</sup>

also this hadith which is recorded by Imam Muslim

> Jabir (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>   A bedouin came to the Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) and asked him, "O Messenger of Allah, what are the two imperatives which lead to Jannah or Hell". He (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) replied, "He who dies without associating anything with Allah will enter Jannah, and he who dies associating partners with Allah will enter the Fire". <sup>[source](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/414)</sup>

So, I hope you find the answer. It is the reward of belief and don't take it lightly. There are many hadith on this.

Answer (score -3):

You will find the answer for this in Quran.These kind of statements are made by people of the book too.

> **79** So woe to those who write the "scripture" with their own hands,
>   then say, "This is from Allah ," in order to exchange it for a small
>   price. Woe to them for what their hands have written and woe to them
>   for what they earn.
>
> **80** And they say, "Never will the Fire touch us,
>   except for a few days." Say, **"Have you taken a covenant with Allah ?**
>   For Allah will never break His covenant. Or do you say about Allah
>   that which you do not know?"
>
> Quran Baqarah

Have your friend taken a covenant with Allah for this claim?.

Hope you find the answer from this Quranic verse