# Is there nobody in Jannah (paradise) yet?

Tags: jannah

I saw this question [Who will be the first person(s) who enter the paradise?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27802/17163) which talks about people going to Jannah (paradise) after the Day of Judgement.  The current answers talk about Prophet Muhammad being the first (or among the first) to enter Jannah.

If I've understood the answers correctly, even the Prophet Muhammad has to wait until the Day of Judgement.  This has the implication that there is nobody currently in Jannah.  Perhaps it exists and is vacant, or it hasn't yet been created.

A hadith was quoted:

> Anas b. Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: I will come to the gate of Paradise on the Day of Resurrection. and would seek its opening. and the keeper would say: Who art thou? I would say: Muhammad. He would then say: It is for thee that I have been ordered, and not to open it for anyone before thee. -- Sahih Muslim 197 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/394))

(I'm not confident if I understood all this correctly.)

**Question**: Is there nobody in Jannah (paradise) yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, there are some but they are only in spirit form

---

Rasul Allah (sal Allahu alaihi wa sallam) said:

> “Their (shuhada’s) souls are in the crops of green birds, which have lamps hanging from the Throne, and they roam freely wherever they want in Paradise, then they return to those lamps. Their Lord looked down upon them and said: ‘Do you desire anything?’ They said: ‘What could we desire, when we can roam freely wherever we want in Paradise?’ He (subhanahu wa ta’ala) did that with them three times, and when they saw that they would not be left without being asked, they said: ‘O Lord, we want You to restore our souls to our bodies so that we may be killed in Your cause again.’ When He saw that they had no need, they were left alone.”
>
> [The Book of Leadership: Sahih Muslim]

As stated in the above hadith, the martyrs are in the form of the green birds enjoying Jannah but when Qiyamah comes they will be restored to their body and enjoy the physical enjoyment of Jannah mentioned in the Qu'ran (See [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16800/would-i-really-enjoy-jannah-paradise-if-at-all-i-manage-to-get-there)). This would be similar to the case of the Prophets as the Rasullulah visited Jannah in his dreams therefore referring to the soul and spirit.

Some say that it appeared to him in dreams and therefore it is a Revelation and some say that Allah showed the Prophet a vision of what is to come.

There is dispute however on whether the Prophet went on Mi'raj in body and spiritual form.

---

In summary, no one has **physically entered** Jannah. This will happen to all destined for Jannah on the Day of Judgement. The martyrs and Prophets are in Jannah but **spiritually** so it doesn't really count as an actual person entering Jannah.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -2):

From this Hadid we may conclude that indeed there are already people in Jannah:

[Bukhari 67:130 (5196)](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5196):

> Usamah bin Zaid reported that the Prophet (pbuh) said "I stood at the gate of Jannah and (I saw) that the majority of those entered are the poor, and the wealthy were kept confined [...]

Comment: This Hadith is regarding the future, after the judgment day.