# Will porn close my dad's doors to Jannah?

Tags: family, pornography

It has been almost 6 years since I first saw my dad watching porn and I've learnt to live with it but now I've started to fear that this will close his doors to Jannah. My dad prays routinely and misses prayers very rarely. My mom is the nicest ever and I've started to give her hints but she doesn't even know what porn is, what is worse is that my mom is more educated than my dad and she has given up everything for the family. I feel like she's being betrayed. I know Allah knows best but please can anyone give me some some good references that will help me get rid of this fear? Please please don't make my situation worse. I should mention that my dad loves my mom a lot too. I hope I'm not asking for a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Pornography by itself is not enough to close the door to Jannah:

> Messenger of Allah, what are the two things quite unavoidable? He replied: He who dies without associating anyone with Allah would (necessarily) enter Paradise and he who dies associating anything with Allah would enter the (Fire of) Hell.
>   <sub>[Sahih Muslim 93 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/175)</sub>

See also [Is this true that all Mumins will eventually go to Paradise?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2404/17163)

Nevertheless, pornography is not considered permissible ([Is pornography allowed in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/21524/17163)).  There's also fairly strong scientific evidence (actual science [peer-reviewed, published papers]) about the harms of pornography usage.  See [Any scientific logic on prohibiting porn (pornography)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30419/17163)

Whether or not masturbation is forbidden is less clear ([Is masturbation permissible for a man during an extended period of unmarried life?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/3004/17163)), but it's universally considered better to zina (a major sin).

(I wouldn't encourage meddling in your parents' sex life.)